# i don't inderstand the problem in my first redux counter

Tags: reactjs, redux, compiler-errors, counter

i have an error in my code

Failed to compile
./src/components/counterTemp.js
Attempted import error: 'decrement' is not exported from '../action/indexAction'.

there is my code>> https://github.com/ennouri0maak/my-error

[ther is the exact error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PjcQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you've to be careful, because by giving it similar names you may have been confused.

What you're importing into the CounterTemp.js file was the name you had defined each of the actions with but not the actual name of your ActionCreators which are actually incrementAction, decrementAction and resetAction. Therefore the import would be:

```
import {
  incrementAction,
  decrementAction,
  resetAction,
} from "../action/indexAction";
```

Also, in your mapDispatchToProps method you can no longer directly assign increment to increment as you used to, but you have to assign the particular ActionCretor, in this case incrementAction, to increment otherwise you will get an error as it will tell you that increment, decrement and reset are undefined, so it would remain:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
      increment: incrementAction,
      decrement: decrementAction,
      reset: resetAction,
    },
    dispatch
  );
}
```

To see what the `CounterTemp.js` code would look like, it would:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import {
  incrementAction,
  decrementAction,
  resetAction,
} from "../action/indexAction";

class Counter extends Component {
  render() {
    const { count, increment, decrement, reset } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Counter</h2>
        <button onClick={decrement}>-</button>
        <span> {count} </span>
        <button onClick={increment}>+</button>
        <br />
        <br />
        <button onClick={reset}>Reset</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    count: state.count,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
      increment: incrementAction,
      decrement: decrementAction,
      reset: resetAction,
    },
    dispatch
  );
}

Counter = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Counter);

export default Counter;
```

PS: barrel files (index files) if you have already nested them in a particular folder just add the name "index.js" because the specificity of what type is given by the folder where it is hosted and not by the index. Therefore, it would be changing from indexAction to index.js so you can import your ActionCreators over `"../action"` and not over `"../action/indexAction"`

Comment: Did you do an npm install of the project before you started it?

Comment: and then just entering those files should do you good, they are hosted in node_modules

Comment: guess what

https://i.imgur.com/NB20NKM.png

thank you awesome devloper  <3.

Answer (score 0):

You do try to import the below from a file that these are not defined. If you wanna import indeed the below import them from indexTypes file although I believe that you want to import the actual acitons.

`import { increment, decrement, reset } from "../action/indexAction";`

Although you have defined your actions as `incrementAction, decrementAction, resetAction`

So you need to do:

```
import {
 incrementAction,
 decrementAction,
 resetAction`
} from '../action/indexActions'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `indexAction.js` does not have any import with the name of `decrement`, `increment`, or `reset`.

So, either you will need to refactor the names in the `indexAction.js`, or need to import in your `counterTemp.js` like the following

```
import {
    incrementAction as increment,
    decrementAction as decrement,
    resetAction as reset
} from "../action/indexAction";
```

instead of

```
import { increment, decrement, reset } from "../action/indexAction";
```